# Resource limits on AWS Temporary Security Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Is it possible to apply resource limits to Temporary Security Credentials?

For example, each credential is only allowed to launch 1x small instance.

If not via IAM, are there any other hooks in place? I'm not able to limit the root account to a single instance, it has to be at the user level.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: You can restrict the instances to be of certain type (like t2.small) but there is no IAM policy to restrict the number of instances.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (as far as I am aware) to use IAM to control the number of instances a particular user can launch. However, you can achieve the same effect by creating a small subnet in your VPC and restrict the launching of instances to that subnet.

If you create `subnet-abcd1234` with CIDR range `10.120.10.0/28` it will give you a total of 14 IPs in the subnet. According to the [AWS documenation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#SubnetSize) IPs 1, 2 and 3 are reserved. This leaves you with only 11 available IPs.

In your IAM policy, you can deny launching instances in any other subnet:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      },
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:123456789012:network-interface/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotEquals": {
          "ec2:Subnet": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:123456789012:subnet/subnet-abcd1234"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `eu-west-1` is the region and `123456789012` is your AWS account ID.

If you want to ensure that only one instance can run in the subnet, you can create ENIs (Elastic Network Interfaces), without attaching them to instances. Here's how to create an interface using Python:

```
import boto.ec2
connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
connection.create_network_interface(subnet_id="subnet-abcd1234",
                                    description="placeholder ENI")
```

If you create 10 ENIs, then attempting to launch more than one instance in the subnet will result in an error, since there are no more available IPs.